# Calculating BPM from an audio file

Tags: audio

How is the bpm calculated for an audio file?

Is this calculated on the bits themselves?

How is a beat interpreted in a sound file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Beats per minute from real-time audio input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79445/beats-per-minute-from-real-time-audio-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this question will be helpful:

[Beats per minute from real-time audio input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79445/beats-per-minute-from-real-time-audio-input)